# ngnix CORS configuration for JIRA api not working

Tags: angularjs, nginx, jira-rest-api

We haven an internal JIRA server running. And I am developing a UI web app with the REST api provided.

My angularjs UI web app runs at `http://127.0.0.1:9000` which hits `http://localhost/jira-api/rest/api/2/...`

To deal with cross domain issues I setup ngnix with below configuration.

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    upstream jiraserver {
        server myjira.com;
    }
    server {
        listen localhost:80;
        server_name localhost;

        location /jira-api {
            rewrite  ^/jira-api/(.*) /$1 break;

            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since';

                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';

                return 204;
            }

             if ($request_method = 'POST') {

                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

             }

             if ($request_method = 'GET') {

                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

             }

            proxy_pass http://jiraserver;
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives me an error for OPTIONS request: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `http://127.0.0.1:9000` is therefore not allowed access.

The *response headers* of the OPTIONS request don't actually have any of the headers that I set above:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Mon, 22 Sep 2014 12:35:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-AREQUESTID: 515x609530x4
X-Seraph-LoginReason: OK
X-ASESSIONID: 10iojgl
X-AUSERNAME: someone
```

Is something wrong with the configuration??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try moving

`rewrite  ^/jira-api/(.*) /$1 break;`

to bottom

`rewrite  ^/jira-api/(.*) /$1 break;
proxy_pass http://jiraserver;`